# Failed to resolve plugin for module "react-native-fbads" relative to [project dir]

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-fbsdk, facebook-ads, react-native-fbads

react-native-fbads: 7.1.0

react-native: 0.68.2

I am using an eas build for a project that is part of a managed expo workflow. I am trying to integrate Facebook ads into the app using [react-native-fbads](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-fbads). After following their expo installation instructions in the main readme, when I attempt to run `eas build --profile development --platform ios` I get the following cryptic error:

`Failed to resolve plugin for module "react-native-fbads" relative to "D:\Projects\pollenbbmap"`

Can anyone help me resolve this error? Happy to provide any additional information.

My app.json looks like this

```
{
  "expo": {
    "owner": "gainesvilleboyz",
    "name": "pollenbbmap",
    "slug": "pollenbbmap",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.arham23.pollenbbmap"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      [
        "react-native-fbsdk-next",
        {
          "appID": "XXXX",
          "clientToken": "XXX",
          "displayName": "Pollen Map App",
          "advertiserIDCollectionEnabled": false,
          "autoLogAppEventsEnabled": false,
          "isAutoInitEnabled": true,
          "iosUserTrackingPermission": "This identifier will be used to deliver personalized ads to you."
        }
      ],
      "react-native-fbads"
    ]
  }
}
```